Internal error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Next.js React
so I've been having this "⨯ Internal error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" for awhile and I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. I'm trying to make it so that when the "Add to Cart" button is clicked, then it increments the amount of items in the cart by 1.
I am using Typescript and Nextjs
Here is my page.tsx:
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { BackgroundGradient } from "../components/ui/background-gradient";
import Image from "next/image";
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar";
import FetchData from "../FetchData";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

interface ShopProps {
  onCount: number;
  onItemPress: (count: number) => void;
}

const Shop: React.FC<ShopProps> = ({ onCount, onItemPress }) => {

    interface Product {
      id: number;
      title: string;
      description: string;
      price: number;
      image: string;
    }
    const [productData, setProductData] = useState<Product[] | null>(null);
    let count = 0;
    

    return (
      <>
        <FetchData onDataReceived={setProductData}>
          {null}
        </FetchData>
        <NavBar />
        
        <div className="rounded-[22px] max-w-sm pt-20">
          {
            productData && (
              <ul>
                  {productData.map((product: Product) => (
                    <BackgroundGradient className="rounded-[22px] max-w-sm p-4 sm:p-10 bg-white dark:bg-zinc-900" key={count}>
                      <li key={product.id}>
                        <Image
                          src={product.image} 
                          alt={product.title}
                          width="400"
                          height="400"
                          className="object-contain"
                        />
                        <p className="text-base sm:text-xl text-black mt-4 mb-2 dark:text-neutral-200">{product.title}</p>
                        <p className="text-sm text-neutral-600 dark:text-neutral-400">{product.description}</p>
                        <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                          <button className="rounded-full pl-4 pr-1 py-1 text-white flex items-center space-x-1 bg-black mt-4 text-xs font-bold dark:bg-zinc-800">
                            <span>Buy now </span>
                            <span className="bg-zinc-700 rounded-full text-[0.6rem] px-2 py-0 text-white">
                            ${product.price}
                            </span>
                          </button>
                          <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                onItemPress(onCount + 1);
                               
                            }} 
                            className="rounded-full pl-4 pr-4 py-1 text-white flex items-center 
                                      justify-center space-x-1 bg-black mt-4 text-xs font-bold dark:bg-zinc-800"
                          >
                            Add to Cart
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      
                    </BackgroundGradient>
                  ))}
              </ul>
            )
          }
          <BackgroundGradient className="rounded-[22px] max-w-sm p-4 sm:p-10 bg-white dark:bg-zinc-900">
            <Image
              src='/og-package-react'
              alt="jordans"
              height="400"
              width="400"
              className="object-contain"
            />
            <p className="text-base sm:text-xl text-black mt-4 mb-2 dark:text-neutral-200">
              Air Jordan 4 Retro Reimagined
            </p>
     
            <p className="text-sm text-neutral-600 dark:text-neutral-400">
              The Air Jordan 4 Retro Reimagined Bred will release on Saturday,
              February 17, 2024. Your best opportunity to get these right now is by
              entering raffles and waiting for the official releases.
            </p>
            <button className="rounded-full pl-4 pr-1 py-1 text-white flex items-center space-x-1 bg-black mt-4 text-xs font-bold dark:bg-zinc-800">
              <span>Buy now </span>
              <span className="bg-zinc-700 rounded-full text-[0.6rem] px-2 py-0 text-white">
                $100
              </span>
            </button>
          </BackgroundGradient>
        </div>
      </>
      );
}

export default Shop;

ShoppingCart.tsx
"use client";
import React from "react";
import Badge from "@material-ui/core/Badge";
import { useState } from 'react';
import ShoppingCartIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCart";
import Shop from "../shop/page";

export default function ShoppingCart() {
    const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState(0);

    const handleItemPress = (newCount: number) => {
        setItemCount(newCount);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <Badge color="secondary" badgeContent={itemCount} overlap="rectangular">
                    <ShoppingCartIcon />
                </Badge>
            </div>
            <Shop onCount={itemCount} onItemPress={handleItemPress} />
        </div>
    );
}

NavBar.tsx
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { HoveredLink, Menu, MenuItem, ProductItem } from "./ui/navbar-menu";
import { cn } from "@/app/utils/cn";
import ShoppingCart from "./ShoppingCart";
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function NavbarDemo() {
  return (
    <div className="relative w-full flex items-center justify-center">
      <Navbar className="top-2" />
      <p className="text-black dark:text-white">
        The Navbar will show on top of the page
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

function Navbar({ className }: { className?: string }) {

  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState<string | null>(null);
  return (
    <div className={cn("fixed top-10 inset-x-0 max-w-2xl mx-auto z-50", className)}>
      <Menu setActive={setActiveItem}>
        <a className="text-white" href="/">Home</a>
        <a className="text-white" href="/shop">Shop</a>
      </Menu>
      <ShoppingCart />
    </div>
  );
}

FetchData.tsx
import { useEffect, useState, ReactNode } from 'react';

interface FetchDataProps {
    children: ReactNode;
    onDataReceived?: (data: any) => void;
}

const FetchData = ({ children, onDataReceived }: FetchDataProps) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=5', {mode: "cors"})
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status >= 400) {
                    throw new Error("server error");
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((fetchedData) => {
                setData(fetchedData);
                if(onDataReceived) {
                    onDataReceived(fetchedData);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => setError(error))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, [onDataReceived]);

    return children;
};

export default FetchData;

I'm trying to make it so that when the "Add to Cart" button is clicked, then it increments the amount of items in the cart by 1.

I guess the issue come from the component "FetchData". Could you show it aslo?
Anyway, I think the FetchData should be a custom hook and should NOT the component like what you did.

@DzunHo Hi, I just added the FetchData.tsx component into my post.

In a closer look, you're having circular rendering in your components hierarchy.
<Shop /> 
=> <> ... <Navbar /> </> 
=> <> ... <ShoppingCart /> </>
=> <> ... <Shop /> </>
=> <> ... <Navbar /> </>  // again 
=> ... infinite loop.

Let's try to remove the "Navbar" from your Shop component and you will see that the loop will end.
If you want to you the  normally, let's remove the "ShoppingCart" component in Navbar.

Hi! Yes I do see that. I want to know how I could include the Navbar without the infinite loop occurring.

@hellokev: If you want to you the normally, let's remove the "ShoppingCart" component in Navbar (updated in the answer also).

Yes, that gets rid of the circular rendering, however I want to be able to have ShoppingCart in my NavBar. How can I do that without having to cause a circular render?
